# Assert that a function is called in code at least 1 occurrence

Tags: c++, assert

Is it possible to do a compile-time-assertion that a function get called at least one **occurrence**?

It is **not** related to how many times the function is executed.

```
//C.h
class C{  //Callee
    void f();
};

//C.cpp
void C::f(){ //note: non static
    assert_called_at_least_once();  //<--- I expected something like this $$
    ............. some complex thing ......
}

//D.cpp
D::f2(){  //Caller
    C c;
    if(false){ 
    //^ This line is to emphasize that I don't care whether c.f() will be executed
        c.f(); //<--- if I comment out this line, an error should occur.
        //( Assume that it is only one occurrence of C::f(). )
    }
}
```

It is for debugging purpose.

### **Edit**

As requested, I will provide more information why I want this feature.

My game has many sub-systems.  C is one of them.

I want to make sure that my game calls a certain function in a certain sub-system (e.g. Bullet System updates bullet's position) at least once.

Here is the reason.

Sometimes, when I want to narrow the scope that a bug can occur, I disable the function by commenting out this line in my big System (D) :-

```
bulletSystem->update();
```

After the bug is found, I sometimes forgot to re-enable it back.

In some cases, it is easier if I can insert an assert line inside the function rather than set breakpoint.

**Edit2:**
I prefer a solution explaining about C++ feature rather than a solution to solve my specific example about game.

If such solution simply does not exist (suggested by M.M and n.m.), please post as an answer, so I can sadly accept it.

**Edit3:**

```
#define #ifdef ... (suggested by rezdm)
```

or other # seem to be useful.

However, I demand a solution that
- the $$-line is replaced by <= 1 line of simple code, because more complexity = more bugs
- does not require any modification in caller (D)

Comment: No, but you could inspect the map file or something to see if the function made it

Comment: If this is really about **compile**-time, then any #define will do the job. Can you elaborate a bit on the problem?

Comment: For troubleshooting, change the name of `C::f()` to something like `C::f_xyzzy()`.  If there's a call to `C::f()`, you'll get a compiler error at the call site.

Comment: @Michael Burr   It works, but not so convenient because I have to change 2 places  (.h & .cpp. , editing .h is also slow when compiled)  , and I have to change rename it back again after testing.

Comment: I agree it's not particularly convenient, but it works.  You can also use good old search functionality of your editor/IDE, many of which support more than a text-based search and will look for a match based on the type of the identifier so you won't get inundated with false positives for common names. For example, my editors support a "Find reference" that will find all the callers to a function.

Comment: @Michael Burr  Yes, it is another solution.  Unfortunately, editor for C++ is usually not so smart. (e.g. Visual Studio with template, a lot of lambda .... )  I don't want to put all of my faith into it / rely on it too much.

Comment: No you cannot have anything like that.

Comment: What about covering this issue in testing stage?

Comment: @rezdm  Do you mean I have to create a (new?) stage to test it, then manually observe it (e.g. if the bullet move)?   Sadly, effect of some functions are not obvious.  It is not automatic = human-error.

Comment: Why manually? You want to test if something is called or not. This can be as following
    #ifdef IN_TEST
        int in_test_mode = -1;
    #else
        int in_test_mode = 0;
    #endif

    D::f2(){ 
        C c;
        if(in_test_mode){ 
            c.f();
        }
    }

    ... testBullet() {
       D d;
       d.f2();
       . check for side-effects of C::f() call and assert if it was not executed
    }

I bet it's possible to ensure that in release configuration this block:
        if(in_test_mode){ 
            c.f();
        }
is ommited by compiler as well

Comment: @rezdm   I kinda understand your solution.  I sometimes do this.  However, I want to know if C++ have such feature, so I am not forced to use if-else (which can introduce another bug).  More solution=better.  Thank!